# How in .htaccess do I return the file requested but then run a PHP script?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mp3

What I am trying to do is collect download data for a podcast. When an episode's .mp3 file gets requested I want to track that to my Google Analytics account.

I've found Stack Overflow articles showing how to redirect a request to a PHP script that tracks the data to Google Analytics and then returns the .mp3 file, however, for some reason this breaks in Safari and in iOS (yet works in Chrome).

This is what I was using for the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*).(mp3) download.php?file=$1.$2 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way to script my .htaccess file to return the file normally, but then call my `download.php` script which will just handle the Google Analytics tracking, and if it fails for whatever reason it won't interfere with the person listening to the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up a script which sends data to Google Analytics server side using [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide), maybe using cURL, and serves the file with proper headers so that there is no redirection involved.

**download.php:**

```php
<?php

$filename = $_GET['file'];

$data = array('v'=>'1',
              'tid'=>'UA-XXXXX-Y',
              'cid'=>'555',
              't'=>'event',
              'ec'=>'sound'
              'ea'=>'download'
              'el'=>$filename);
$url = 'https://google-analytics.com/collect';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);

if(file_exists($filename)) {
    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="test.mp3"');
    header('Content-length: '.filesize($filename));
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked"); 

    readfile($filename);
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

Alternatively you can try parsing apache access logs with a cron job script but that seems memory consuming and too complicated.

**EDIT:** I added in GAMP code and changed over the syntax to be more positive